# Using firestore version 9 getting an error when submitting data to store

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore from firebase version 9 and I am trying to set data to the firestore and get the below error. Im using example code from the internet that should work, but anything I've tried so far hasn't worked.

```
  async function submitFireStoreReels() {
    const db = FirebaseUtil.fireStore()
    try {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    first: "Alan",
    middle: "Mathison",
    last: "Turing",
    born: 1912
  });

  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
  }
```

[image]

My FirebaseUtil file looks like

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app'
import { getStorage, FirebaseStorage } from 'firebase/storage'
import { getFirestore, Firestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
class FirebaseUtil {
  initFirebase(): void {
    // Initialize firebase
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_KEY,
      projectId: '12345',
      authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
      databaseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
      storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET
    }
    if (!getApps().length) {
      initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    } else {
      getApp()
    }
  }

  firebaseStorage(): FirebaseStorage {
    return getStorage(getApp())
  }

  fireStore(): Firestore {
    return getFirestore()
  }
}

export default new FirebaseUtil()
```

Comment: Can you show us the error message to? The sintax for `adding` not setting looks ok but the `FirebaseUtil.fireStore()` is strange. What does that do and is it using the new SDK?

Comment: @TarikHuber just updated and pasted my firebaseutil file.

Comment: @TarikHuber I don't see the network error anymore, but im also not seeing my document being uploaded into firestore as expected. and help on my `submitFireStoreReels()` function that might be the problem?

Comment: The code looks fine. Do you see any other error messages? Do you use the right Firebase project? Did the anser below help you remove the first problem?

Comment: @TarikHuber yeah the solution below helped solve the first problem.

Comment: It would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your data update on Firebase?

Can you try initializing you database like this:

```js
fireStore(): Firestore {
    return initializeFirestore(firebaseApp, {useFetchStreams:false} as any)
}
```

Over [here](https://githubmemory.com/repo/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5302) it solved the issue.

Comment: that really did the trick! thank you :)